# How to simulate water pushing a wheel

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

I would like to make a water wheel that can be rotated due to flowing water. I made the wheel as an obstacle and enable collision physics. Is it possible to let the water (fluid simulation) interact with the turbine (rigid body physics)?  Thanks :)

Comment: Are you stating that your wheel is static upon collision? If so, (assuming you already applied collision physics) then maybe the wheel has too much mass.

Comment: It doesn't seem to interact. Should I make the wheel as a rigid body?

Comment: I don't know. Try the collision instead of ridgid body.